# List Activity in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, listactivity

A list activity class extends ListActivity for creating list menu. As java doesn't allow multiple inheritance and a fragment class already extends Fragment than how can i make a list menu in a fragment? or there is an alternative method for doing so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this demo for ListActivity : http://androidexample.com/Create_Listview_With_ListActivity_-_Android_Example%20/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=66&aaid=91

Comment: list activity is a activity which can have fragment.

Comment: `or there is an alternative method for doing so?` Yes: a plain Fragment with a ListView inside. No ListActivity, no ListFragment needed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) instead of `Fragment`

> A fragment that displays a list of items by binding to a data source
>   such as an array or Cursor, and exposes event handlers when the user
>   selects an item.

Here is [a simple tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_fragment.htm) to show how it is used.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use an activity and use a ListFragment and in `onActivityCreated(Bundle b)`, just do the following:
`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. Maybe I'm not understanding your question otherwise... No need for that multiple inheritance complication.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `ListFragment`, you can create your own `ListView` within an empty `Fragment`.

Tutorial: [Create a simple ListView](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65).

Answer (score 0):

You simply add a listView in your fragment layout file and use it in your fragment class. the method you are using is quite old.